# Delphi. How to stop editor from autoinserting comments?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

In Delphi 10.4 Sydney, if you select a comment, for example `//xxx` and then press press `{` on your keyboard, the editor will automatically replace the selected text/comment with `{//xxx}`.

The expected behavior would be to have only `{` on the screen, instead of `{//xxx}`.

How do I stop this behavior?

I disabled all my IDE experts, so this must be from the IDE itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a general feature not related to comments.

If you have anything selected and type an opening bracket like `(` or `{`, you will automatically surround the selection with this bracket. For instance, if you select `cat` and type `(`, you will end up with `(cat)`.

This can be particularly annoying when the IDE helps you with an `if` statement: If you type `if` and then a space, the IDE automatically inserts `if True then` with `True` selected. If you then type `(` (for instance, if you want to type `(a = 1) and (b = 4)`), you will end up with `if (True) then`, and not `if ( then`.

To disable this feature, go to **Tools**, **Options**, **User Interface**, **Editor Options**, **Key Mappings**, **Enhancement modules** and deselect **Smart Surround Keys**:

[image: Screenshot of dialog box]

Comment: Sooo many thanks Andreas! That feature should be called "Annoying surround keys" instead of "Smart surround keys".

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience: Sometimes this feature can actually be convenient, but it certainly takes some time to get used to.

Comment: Going to read the manual for the rest of those features. Goodies!!! Hope I can disable more stuff.

Comment: And because we are here. To disable another annoying (new) tool "Navigation toolbar" (the one that appears in the top of editor):
    Go to Tools > Options > Editor Options > Display->Show navigation toolbar

Comment: Actually, the navigation toolbar can be useful, but it takes a while to get used to. Also, it takes up valuable vertical space, so to really appreciate it, you'd need a 4K monitor.